# What part should I buy to render videos?

Tags: hardware

I want to create & render videos (using SonyVegas, Adobe Premiere) to get fast rendering speed. I have optimized the program codecs/bitrates, but now want optimize hardware too:

Can I ignore CPU (they were used in the past) and just buy a good videocard (a.k.a. GPU) ? 
Or does there exist  any special external part (attachable miner or etc..) , like this:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you in search of a "solution" when you appear to have NOT identified a "problem"?  Are you editing video now?  Is it too slow for what you need? Are you making artificially unreasonable assumptions about how fast video rendering should be? Can you change your workflow to reduce or eliminate high-end solutions to a low-end requirement?  For example to let videos render overnight while you are sleeping (or over the lunch-hour when you are eating, etc.)

Your question very much seems like a solution in search of a problem. That is typically followed by an ill-considered waste of money.

Are there fast solutions to video rendering?  Certainly.  Do people need that kind of solution? Yes, of course.  Do YOU need that kind of solution?  You have presented no evidence that you even know how fast videos will render on your current hardware, and whether that is insufficient for your (also unstated) requirements.

I must agree with the other responses that anything going through a USB2 is dead in the water if you are seeking truly fast video rendering. It is just a joke.

Answer (score 3):

CPU's used to render graphics was a very very long time ago. GPU's surpassed CPU's for this almost 20 years ago. You absolutely do need to get a good graphics card, yes. Don't look for anything external - the amount of data transferred in and out of the graphics card means running through an interface will be so slow as to be unusable.

You'll want one of the cards from [this list](http://www.techradar.com/news/computing-components/graphics-cards/best-graphics-cards-1291458):

- Nvidia Titan X.
- EVGA GeForce GTX 1080 Founders Edition.
- Zotac GeForce GTX 980Ti AMP Extreme Edition.
- Gigabyte Radeon R9 Fury X.
- Sapphire Radeon R9 Nano.
- MSI GeForce 1070 Gaming X.
- Nvidia GeForce 1050 Ti.
- AMD Radeon RX 480.

And more than likely, if you have never done this before, you'll need to get yourself a new motherboard to support the graphics card. And look at fast disk...

Answer (score 1):

If by 'render videos' you mean exporting video files from editor and compositing apps, then the CPU is still primary. Yes, many apps/encoders do use CUDA/OpenCL APIs to use the GPU to render videos but the quality for a given bitrate isn't quite there yet.

If you mean the viewport preview of your edit/FX then get a good graphics card as per Dr. Mayhem.

Comment: Oh - that's a good point. I was assuming front end rendering.

Comment: @DrMayhem and Mylvya, please explain me, i dont know why you gave different answers... I just want to use SonyVegas(or Premiere) to create and render videos.

Comment: Hm.. Do you mean, that Rendered using CPU and GPU (with same bitrate), CPU has  a better quality???

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Vegas, then AMD GPUs, Premier Nvidia. The newer intel cpus have built in graphics support for opencl 1.2 and specific instructions for video encoding/decoding. Getting a new Quadcore 6th gen I7 and the AMD RX480 will help, but also should get fastest HDs or SSDS you can afford.